# Jenkins GIT_ASKPASS Getting FATAL: null

Tags: jenkins

I have a new Jenkins server with GitHub plugin installed.  I defined credentials and when I go to the configuration for the script it does not show me an error with github credentials.  And when I click on github from the menu github opens to my repository.

However, when I do a build I get the error below.  I have no idea what is the problem so hoping someone could point me.  I am also not sure why it says recommended git tool is none

```
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\ConnexV4
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential <<cred>>
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository <<repo>>
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe init C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\ConnexV4 # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from <<repo>>
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.33.0.windows.2'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubAppCredentials.getToken(GitHubAppCredentials.java:275)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubAppCredentials.getPassword(GitHubAppCredentials.java:303)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.createPasswordFile(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2415)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2060)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:86)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:624)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:853)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1227)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1305)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1213)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:637)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:509)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:432)
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept poking at this and found the github repository I was putting was not correct - I ended up using a version of the url that has a long number at the front